# Deploy a .NET library

Tags: .net, deployment

I'm trying to deploy a .NET library using WiX.

The MSI copy the library in the GAC (Global Assembly Cache), and I can find my library on Windows\Assembly. "Cool" I said.

But probably I missed something important, since installed applications using that .NET library doesn't find the assembly, and Visual Studio is unable to offer the library for referencing it in projects.

As conclusion, it seems that installing the .NET library in the GAC doesn't bring any benefit, since it cannot be loaded and it cannot be used for developing. Of course I can copy DLL in the application working copy, and of course a can include in the PATH environment the installation path...

...but how I can deploy a .NET assembly and integrate it on the host system without duplicating files and modify the environment?

Comment: To work on x64 platforms, it's necessary to set also:

[
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\AssemblyFolders]

or

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\AssemblyFolders]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [this](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=306149). Installing assembly into GAC doesn't automatically make it appear in the add reference box. There are some additional steps that need to be done.

Comment: Good! Much thanks. But what about the library loading from an installed application?

Comment: As far as I understand it, if you put it into the GAC and reference it in the way they describe, the deployed app will be actually able to work with the library from GAC.